# regular expression to match CSS "<property>: <value>"

Tags: javascript, regex

I've retrieved a CSS rule from `document.styleSheets` and am looking now to extract it's properties and values.

```
cssText = ".expl { position: absolute; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); max-width: 150px; }";
```

Is it possible with regular expressions to retrieve the properties and their appropriate values within a match? Plus, strip the trailing semi-colon.

I want to get the result as follows:

```
position: absolute // match 1
background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204) // match 2
max-width: 150px // match 3
```

I've only got to the point where I'm extracting what's within the brackets: `(?<={)(.*)(?=})`, have no clue with what should I continue.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not split the string in to array and loop through it ?

Comment: were you aware that cssText doesn't include the selector? so your example would be `cssText = "position: absolute; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); max-width: 150px; "`

Comment: You don't need a regexp for this at all. Use the CSS stylesheet DOM. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/stylesheets.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just split the string on the `;`

```
document.getElementById(id).style.cssText.split(";")
```

EDIT:

note that the cssText property of a style object does not contain the selector

[image]

EDIT 2:

Ok I did a little more digging and it appears you are getting your cssText property from a CSSStyleRule object.  This includes the selectors.  You can get a semicolon delimited list of the actual rules with a little more tree traversal.  You can get the style object with

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.cssText;
```

instead of

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].cssText;
```

See this drill down:

[image]

Comment: Apparently someone is going through and just downvoting everything in this thread.

Comment: Oh, I guess should've descended one more time, heh.. Because you answered first, plus the effort- answer goes to you. Thanks!

Comment: Note: It is not 100% reliable. For instance, `background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,.....");`

Answer (score 3):

Pull everything out between the brackets and then just split it out:

```
matches = cssrule.match(/{([^}]+)}/);
rules = matches[1].split(';');
```

Comment: oh! I see why you did that... I think the OP misunderstands though.  the cssText property doesn't include the selector.

Comment: @Joseph, it retrieves selector on Chrome when gathered by `cssRules`. Maybe `rules` acts differently.

Comment: cssText is just happens to be his variable name. I think that's confusing the issue. It's not the cssText property.

Comment: @Cfreak no, he said he got it from document.styleSheets... I see what happened... going to update my answer again.

Comment: It actually is the `cssText` property, and as I've already said, it contains the selector. At least on Chrome it is.

Answer (score 2):

My regexp is a bit rusty, but something like:

```
var arr = cssText.replace(/\s/g,'')
                 .replace(/^.*{([^}]+)}.*/,'$1')
                 .match(/([^;]+)/g);
```

should create:

```
["position:absolute","background-color:rgb(204,204,204)","max-width:150px"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This breaks it all out into named items

```
\s*(?<rule>(?<selector>[^{}]+){(?<style>[^{};]+:[^{};]+;\s*)+})
```

If your parser doesn't support named groups (which javascript doesn't) remove the `?<text>` from the regex, like this

```
\s*(([^{}]+){([^{};]+:[^{};]+;\s*)+})
```

Since your cssText may not contain the css selector, you may want to just split on `;`.  If it doesn't this works pretty good for parsing stylesheets.  I used it in a tool I wrote to inline stylesheets.